# XSLT compare Dates

Tags: date, xslt, compare

Currently I'm struggeling to get to dates compared. More presizely I have a Person which has an attribute Death with the formatting YYYY-MM-DD and if the person is dead (Death < Currentdate) I want to write a latin-cross.

I tried the following approach:

```
<xsl:if test="@Death &lt;= current-date()">'symbol'</xsl:if>
```

But I only  receive parsing errors form the browser. I'm using XSL version 1.0 with no namespaces except xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" of course.

Where is the error?

Comment: `current-date()` is available in XSLT 2.0, but not in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: "*if the person is dead (Death < Currentdate)*" You have people with dates of death **in the future??!** Who do you work for?

Comment: But would this syntax work?
@michael.hor257k the fact that non skilled users are able to submit xml forces me to check it

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to know how to determine if a date was before the current date.

Comment: As stated already, you cannot perform such test in XSLT 1.0 natively. Some processors support getting the current date through extension mechanisms. But if you intend to perform the transformation in the client's browser, you won't know in advance what the processor supports. Perhaps you can use Javascript to perform the transformation, and pass the current date as the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the particular semantics of what it means for a date of death to be in the future, the general problem of comparing dates in YYYY-MM-DD format can be solved as follows:

- In XSLT 2.0, use `xs:date($x) < xs:date($y)`
- In XSLT 1.0, use `number(translate($x, '-', '')) < number(translate($x, '-', '')`. This is because in XSLT 1.0, the "<" operator only applies to numbers, and we can convert the date to a (meaningless but comparable) number by stripping the hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that:

```
<xsl:if test="@Death">
```

should be quite sufficient for testing. That is unless the living people have an empty `Death` attribute. In such case use:

```
<xsl:if test="string(@Death)">
```